# error in replacing NAs with sequence of numbers of varying length for a variable in dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe which contains many variables, but I would want to focus on only one, 'X', as shown below:

```
df <- data.frame("x" = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1,"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1))
```

What I want to do is to fill numbers in sequence starting from 2 in a way:

1. when there is x==1, next NA should take 2, 3, 4 and so forth, until, again x==1 arrives and then next NA should start filling with 2,3,4, and so forth.

Example output:

```
x = 2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1 ......
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
df$Sequence <- ifelse(df1$x!="1" & is.na(df1$x), seq(2,100), df1$x)
```

But this is not returning me the expected output, why?

Comment: The character string `"NA"` is not the same as the `NA` logical constant that indicates a missing value. Therefore, with your data, `is.na()` will always return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `x` starts with 8 consecutive `NA`, it is still unclear on how to impute the very first rows. Why does your example output start with 2? Here is how to impute everything beginning from the first occurrence of 1. I modified the example by let it start from 1:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame("x" = c(1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1))

df <-
  df %>%
  na_if("NA") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())

y <-
  df %>%
  filter(x == 1) %>%
  # calculate block sizes
  transmute(
    from = id,
    to = lead(id),
    diff = to - from
  ) %>%
  # vector ends with a 1 and there is no n+1 th element
  replace_na(list(diff = 1)) %>%
  pull(diff) %>%
  map(seq) %>%
  flatten() %>%
  as.numeric()
y
#>  [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6
#> [39] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1

df %>% transmute(x, y = y)
#> # A tibble: 48 x 2
#>    x         y
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 1         1
#>  2 <NA>      2
#>  3 <NA>      3
#>  4 <NA>      4
#>  5 <NA>      5
#>  6 <NA>      6
#>  7 <NA>      7
#>  8 <NA>      8
#>  9 1         1
#> 10 <NA>      2
#> # … with 38 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Same approach as @danlooo but using data.table instead of tidyverse

```
df <- data.table(x = as.integer(c(1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1,"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 1)))

df[, id := .I][!is.na(x), diff := lead(id) - id][is.na(diff), diff := 1L][, y := unlist(mapply(seq, df[x == 1L]$diff))][, c("id", "diff") := NULL]
```

If you want to see what is does you need to learn how data.table chains and works by reference.
I advice you to take a look step by step unchaining my code like this.
If you now run line by line you can see what the df table looks after each step

```
## tidyverse
# mutate(id = row_number())

## data.table
df[, id := .I] # adds a column id where .I is the row number

## tidyverse
# y <-
#  df %>%
#  filter(x == 1) %>%
#  transmute(
#    from = id,
#    to = lead(id),
#    diff = to - from
#  )

## data.table
# instead of creating a new object y first I calculate where available the difference
df[!is.na(x), diff := lead(id) - id] # if x is not NA (x==1 would give same result) create diff column (does the same as the transmute()

## tidyverse
# replace_na(list(diff = 1))

## data.table
df[is.na(diff), diff := 1L] # if diff is NA, assign the value 1 (1L stands for 1 as an integer) to diff

## tidyverse
# pull(diff) %>%
# map(seq) %>%
# flatten()
# as.numeric()
# df %>% transmute(x, y = y)

## data.table
# here I directly add the column y where df[x == 1L]$diff "pulls" the diff column with the rows where x == 1, mapply replaces the map() and in this context I need unlist() instead of flatten()
# no need to make numeric, as I made all integers at start (could have chosen numeric as well)
# I did not leave df, so I did not have to recreate df
df[, y := unlist(mapply(seq, df[x == 1L]$diff))]
# as I did not have to recreate df, I need to clean the "help" columns
df[, c("id", "diff") := NULL]
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you please also include some explanation of the code for the readers like me who'd find it a bit difficult to understand. I am sure this should be a great work too, but I was not able to make some sense on to how this code works.

Comment: I have added a more detailed explanation and compared the steps with the tidyverse method.

Comment: wow. this is great too... thanks for sharing tips and work around. awesome!